# Problema ao receber valor em um select com richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, rich-faces

Bom dia galera, estou precisando de ajuda no exemplo abaixo:

```
 <rich:select value="#{bdaBean.argosDocum.localizacaoObra}"  disabled="#{not(bdaBean.usuarioPodeAtualizarBDA)}" height="20px" style="padding-right:10px; margin-botton:30px;" enableManualInput="true" itemValue="bdaBean.listaCodob">
      <f:selectItems value="#{bdaBean.listaCodob}" />
 </rich:select>
      <h:inputText  value="#{bdaBean.argosDocum.localizacaoObra.item}" disabled="#{not(bdaBean.usuarioPodeAtualizarBDA)}" style="padding-bottom: -; border-bottom-width: 1px; margin-top: 8px; height:15px;" />
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Em bdaBean.argosDocum.localizacaoObra vem um valor padrão inicial desta lista, eu gostaria de mudar esse valor após ser selecionado algum elemento dessa lista para alterar o item no input text automaticamente.

Como devo fazer?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de você fazer isso é usando ajax, para o JSF existe um componente para você trabalhar com ajax usando richfaces é o a4j. No showcase deles você pode ver esse [exemplo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=selectsUpdates&skin=ruby). Lembrando que o richfaces foi [descontinuado](https://developer.jboss.org/people/michpetrov/blog/2016/02/12/the-future-of-richfaces) em 2016 então para novos projetos usando JSF seria bom você buscar outras alternativas.